# Count all rows in tableview where name is equal to

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to count all data in a tableview where name is equal to a specific name, but I'm lost and I'm not sure how I can move on, so I'm here asking for your help!

So first off, I've a tableview with a lot of rows. And all of them has dognames inside the cell.

[image: img]

How can I count how many "Selma", "Lexi" and "Lexi & Selma" there is inside this tableview? I wanna count the names so it will looks like this:

```
Selma: 21
Lexi: 10 
Lexi & Selma: 35
```

How can I do that? If you know the answer of this question, please let me know. :) It would really help me out a lot! :)

Comment: The table view is irrelevant. Access the data you used to populate the table view.

Comment: @rmaddy How do you mean? :) Mind if you explain in more detailed way?

Comment: Could you include the struct/class that holds the data of a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show this tableview you have some data (datasource).

Then, it depends on your datasource, the same you pass to the tableview.

You, depending on your datasource (array, dictionary, etc), should group this kind of data.

There a lot of group functions you can use but it depends on the datasource structure.

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let time: String
}


let array = [Person(name: "Selma", time: "12:15"),
                     Person(name: "Lexi", time: "13:15"),
                     Person(name: "Selma", time: "14:15"),
                     Person(name: "Lexi", time: "15:15"),
                     Person(name: "Lexi & Selma", time: "15:15"),
                     Person(name: "Lexi", time: "15:15"),
                     Person(name: "Lexi", time: "15:15"),
                     Person(name: "Lexi & Selma", time: "16:15"),
                     Person(name: "Selma", time: "17:15")]



let set = NSCountedSet(array: array.map{ $0.name })        
set.forEach{ print("\($0): \(set.count(for: $0))") }
```